# Read content of text file in c++ line wise

Tags: c++, file, text, lines

I want to show the content of text file 20 lines on screen.
**User press 'n' to show next 20 lines and 'p' to show previous 20 lines.**
I don't know why its not working.

Here is my code:

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char *s,key;
    int pos;
    fstream f;
    f.open("menu.cpp",ios::in);
    while(1)
    {
        key=getch();
        switch(key)
        {
            case 'n':
                    //read more 20 lines
                    clrscr();
                    for(int i=1;i<=25;i++)
                    {
                        f.getline(s,100);
                        pos=f.tellg();
                        cout<<s<<endl;
                    }
                    break;
            case 'p':   //read previous 20 lines
                    clrscr();
                    f.seekg(-pos);
                                        for(int i=1;i<=25;i++)
                    {
                        f.getline(s,100);

                        cout<<s<<endl;
                    }
                                        break;
            case 'e':
                    clrscr();
                    cout<<"exit";
                    exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably also post what it's actually doing so people don't have to compile and run the program. And/or any error messages you're getting.

Comment: oh..i forgot to mention that...
The next 20 lines are displaying correctly, but previous 20 lines are not displaying when i press 'p', and after that when i press 'e' program doesn't exit also.

Answer (score 1):

First, `s` is uninitialized, so `f.getline(s,100)` is undefined behavior (it's writing to some arbitrary location in memory).

Next, your `for` loop counts to 25, not 20. I assume this is a simple typo either in the code or the question/comment.

Finally, your seek logic is incorrect. You're rereading `pos` each time you read a line of text, so you're only going to seek back one line, not 20/25 lines. Moreover the argument to `seekg()` is an absolute position, so you shouldn't negate it.

EDIT: You should also initialize `pos` to zero, so that if the first key the user presses is `p` you seek to the beginning of the file. Otherwise if `p` is the first keypress the behavior is undefined since you're seeking to an uninitialized offset.

You should also check for EOF each time you try to read a line, so that your program behaves correctly when the end of the file is reached.

Comment: but i thought seekg() function moves file pointer backwards if i will provide -ve value of pos.

So finally what you suggest?

Comment: @ArunSharma Only if you use the 2-argument version and specify `ios_base::cur`. The 1-argument version of `seekg()` takes an absolute file position. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/

Comment: @ArunSharma The argument to the one parameter form of `seekg` is _not_ an integral type; as far as I can tell, unary `-` is not, or should not be defined for it.  (Both VC++ and g++ seem to define it, but they don't tell me what the semantics are.  And of course, `streampos(-1)` is used to signal an error.)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it so complex. Just read the file to a vector at program start and catch keyboard input (not tested):

```
std::vector<std::string> fileContent;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
    fileContent.push_back(line);  // in the end, the file is stored in the STL container

unsigned long lineTracker = 0;  //to make the whole thing buffer-overflow-safe
while(true)
{
    key = getch();
    switch(key)
    {
        case 'n':
            //read more 20 lines
            clrscr();
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < 20 && lineTracker < fileContent.size(); ++i, ++lineTracker)
                std::cout << fileContent[lineTracker];
            break;

        case 'p':
            clrscr();
            lineTracker -= 20;
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < 20 && lineTracker >= 0; ++i, ++lineTracker)
                std::cout << fileContent[lineTracker];
            break;
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggested implementation.  Feel free to ask questions about how it works, if that is not clear.

Among the main features

- Uses std::string instead of char *
- Is broken into small-ish functions
- Uses a class to encapsulate the data and methods

  ```
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <conio.h>  // for getch()

  class CFileViewer
  {
  public:
      CFileViewer(const std::string &sFileName);
      void Show();

  protected:
      void InitFile(const std::string &sFileName);
      void ShowPage();
      bool GetInput();
      static size_t LinesPerPage() { return 25; };

  private:
      size_t                 m_nPage;
      std::vector<long long> m_vPos;
      std::ifstream          m_file;
  };

  CFileViewer::CFileViewer(const std::string &sFileName)
  : m_nPage(0)
  {
      m_vPos.push_back(0);
      InitFile(sFileName);
  }

  void CFileViewer::InitFile(const std::string &sFileName)
  {
      m_file.open(sFileName);
      if (!m_file)
          throw std::runtime_error("cannot open file");
  }

  void CFileViewer::ShowPage()
  {
      // clear any previous eof state
      m_file.clear();

      // goto required part of file
      m_file.seekg(m_vPos.at(m_nPage));

      std::string s;
      for (size_t i=0; i<LinesPerPage(); ++i)
      {
          if (std::getline(m_file, s))
              std::cout << s << std::endl;
          else if (m_file.eof())
              break;
          else
              throw std::runtime_error("error reading file");
      }
      // if we just read a page and it was the last in m_vPos, save
      // current pos as start of next page
      // NB m_nPage will not be incremented if we're at eof.
      if (!m_file.eof() && ++m_nPage == m_vPos.size())
          m_vPos.push_back(m_file.tellg());
  }

  bool CFileViewer::GetInput()
  {
      while (1)
      {
          switch (_getch())
          {
              case 'p':
                  if (m_nPage > 1)
                      m_nPage -= 2;
                  else
                      m_nPage = 0;
                  return true;

              case 'e':
                  std::cout << "exit\n";
                  return false;

              case 'n':
                  if (!m_file.eof())
                      return true;
                  // else
                  std::cout << "at eof\n";
                  // fall through

              default:
                  putchar('\a');
          }
      }
  }

  void CFileViewer::Show()
  {
      do
      {
          ShowPage();
      }
      while (GetInput());
  }


  int main()
  {
      try
      {
          CFileViewer fv("menu.txt");
          fv.Show();
      }
      catch (std::exception &e)
      {
          std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```